# How to find total loss, accuracy, prediction date time using Keras Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, jupyter

I am trying to predict the OHLC values. Till now I have achieved this:
[Jupyter Note of the complete code](https://github.com/JafferWilson/test-Kaggle/blob/master/Kaggle%20source.ipynb)

As one can see my code is running. But I have few doubts regarding the model that I have created.

1. I do not know how much accurate the output was predicted.
2. Whether the error loss improved or not.

I could not even understand why the predictions made do not have date and time along with them on the graph? I want to know for what date the prediction was made.

How I can achieve the goal? Is there a way I can combine the OHLC with the time of prediction?

Answer (score 3):

To have those metrics use:

> [On the docs page of metrics of Keras](https://keras.io/metrics/)
>
> ## Usage of metrics
>
> A metric is a function that is used to judge the performance of your model. Metric functions are to be supplied in the  metrics parameter when a model is compiled.
>
> A metric function is similar to a loss function, except that the results from evaluating a metric are not used when training the model.
>
> ```
> model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='sgd', metrics=['mae', 'acc'])
> ```
>
> You can either pass the name of an existing metric, or pass a Theano/TensorFlow symbolic function (see Custom metrics).
>
> #### Arguments
>
> y_true: True labels. Theano/TensorFlow tensor.
>
> y_pred: Predictions. Theano/TensorFlow tensor of the same shape as y_true.
>
> #### Returns
>
> Single tensor value representing the mean of the output array across all datapoints.

And to evaluate the performance of the model once trained you can use

> [On the docs page of Model of Keras](https://keras.io/models/model/)
>
> ## evaluate
>
> ```
> evaluate(self, x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, verbose=1, sample_weight=None, steps=None)
> ```
>
> #### Returns
>
> the loss value & metrics values for the model in test mode.

#### In your case

I guess you just have to change these rows:

```py
model_open.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
model_high.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
model_low.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
model_close.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

to

```py
model_open.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['mae', 'acc'])
model_high.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['mae', 'acc'])
model_low.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['mae', 'acc'])
model_close.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['mae', 'acc'])
```

and at the end evaluate the models with:

```py
model_open.evaluate( testX_open, testY_open)
model_high.evaluate( testX_high, testY_high)
model_low.evaluate(  testX_low,  testY_low)
model_close.evaluate(testX_close,testY_close)
```

To add metrics like accuracy acc on the training bar you just have to modifiy the compile statement like this.

Comment: I am trying it. Can you also let me know the answer to question "I even could not understand why the predictions made are not having date and time along with them on the graph? I want to know for what date the prediction was made."

Comment: `model_close.evaluate(testX_close,trainY_close)` Is this statement correct? Do I need to verify `testX_close` with `trainY_close` or with `testY_close`?

Comment: Got error while running `evaluate()`: `ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 6039 input samples and 24160 target samples.`

Comment: you are right, it's `model_close.evaluate(testX_close,testY_close)` not `model_close.evaluate(testX_close,trainY_close)` sorry for the mistake, I already edited the answer to correct it.

Comment: And for date and time from what I see from your code, you trained hte LSTM Network to predict the next value from the current one, and in the dataset there's a value every hour. So I guess that will hold in the prediction so that if you make it start to predict from 10 values  where the last one is at 10:00 of  2018.06.01 I guess that the first predicted value will be of 11:00 of  2018.06.01 and the second predicted value will be of 12:00 of 2018.06.01 and so on. This makesense beacuse the Network only know the existance of a step of time, not an actual Date or time.

Comment: There are values every minute, i.e. One minute , and not every hour.